# how to create cluster key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, clustered-index, secondary-indexes

I have a table rooms and user. In the table user I want store room_id is the cluster key and id_user can be duplicate. Example room1 have user (1,2,3..), room2 have users (1,2,3). And name of user can be different ex: with room1 i have the id user is 1 and name is Joni, but room2  id user is 1 and name can be Joini or Sam.
But with can't duplicate when have sample the room_id and user_id. ex the room1 have user 1, it can't have a row second stored the room1 and user 1.

[image]

it's sample cassandra db

Comment: Is not clear but seems you are looking for a composite unique index .. you want that  the couple  id_room, id_user is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be you are looking for a composite unique index (key)

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` ADD UNIQUE `room_user_index`(`id_room`, `id_user`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify both of id_rooms and id_user columns as primary key (composite primary key) then a clustered index and unique key will be created.

The order of composite keys is important for look up speed.

I suggest you study about **relational** dbms concepts to obtain better vision.